# How to setup Fake Reponsitory using Moq With dependency Injection (Error Casting Queryable)

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, moq, xunit

How can I setup Data Queryable Data Using Moq

1. I have The Reponsitory (IMediaCoverageReponsitory).

   ```
   public interface IMediaCoverageRepository : RepositoryAsync<MediaCoverage>
   ```
2. I create Moq IMediaCoverageRepository using Moq

   ```
   var mockFactory = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict) { 
       DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock
   };
   var mockMediaRepository = mockFactory.Create<IMediaCoverageRepository>();
   ```
3. I have a list example:

   ```
   var listOfMediaCoverages = new List<MediaCoverage>()
   {
       new MediaCoverage { MediaCoverageId = 1, Name = "Media 10", IsActive = true },
       new MediaCoverage {MediaCoverageId = 2, Name = "Media 100", IsActive = true },
       new MediaCoverage {MediaCoverageId = 3, Name = "Media 1000", IsActive = false }
   };
   ```
4. After that, I setup data using listOfMediaCoverage Fake Into Mock MediaCoverageRepository like this

   ```
   var queryableListMediaCoverage = listOfMediaCoverages.ToArray().AsQueryable();
   ```

   ```
   mockMediaRepository.Setup(r => r.Queryable(null).GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryableListMediaCoverage.GetEnumerator());
   mockMediaRepository.Setup(r => r.Queryable(null).Provider).Returns(queryableListMediaCoverage.Provider);
   mockMediaRepository.Setup(r => r.Queryable(null).ElementType).Returns(queryableListMediaCoverage.ElementType);
   mockMediaRepository.Setup(r => r.Queryable(null).Expression).Returns(queryableListMediaCoverage.Expression);
   ```

> ==> I get the error: 
>   **Unable to cast object of type
>
> ```
> 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Pacman2.Core.Entities.MediaCoverage]' to type 'Moq.IMocked'.**
> ```

Please Help me solve this problem. I already search on google And  try the solution on this link but won't solve the problem

```
<links>
     http://davidcondemarin.blogspot.com/2012/07/testing-sarp-lite-repositories-with-moq.html
</links>
```

- Notes:
- r => r.Queryable(null) Is the method return IQueryable

Answer (score 0):

```
mockMediaRepository.As<IQueryable<MediaCoverage>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryableListMediaCoverage.Provider);
mockMediaRepository.As<IQueryable<MediaCoverage>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryableListMediaCoverage.Expression);
mockMediaRepository.As<IQueryable<MediaCoverage>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryableListMediaCoverage.ElementType);
mockMediaRepository.As<IQueryable<MediaCoverage>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryableListMediaCoverage.GetEnumerator());
```

Comment: Thank For Your Quick Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with this code

`mockMediaRepository.Setup(r => r.Queryable(It.IsAny())).Returns(queryableListMediaCoverage)`

==> The pronlem is I want to populate the method Queryable with is return IQueryable. And Moq have populate it for me.